# Posting to Consecutive Commands to Solr - Data Missing from 1st Call

Tags: perl, solr, lucene

I am sending the following commands with

```
    my $url = "http://xxxxx/solr/inventory/update?commitWithin=1000";
```

I am using perl to send to a solr setup on another server.

Please excuse the formatting. I really did try.

Thanks
Mike

RESULTING DATA - The data from the first command is not here. All subsequent calls are.

```
{  
   "responseHeader":{  
      "status":0,
      "QTime":0,
      "params":{  
         "q":"*:*",
         "fq":"id:3-159682",
         "_":"1529984183431"
      }
   },
   "response":{  
      "numFound":1,
      "start":0,
      "docs":[  
         {  
            "checklist_id":249746,
            "brand_s":"Pinnacle",
            "featured":"",
            "sf_set_sort":"Baseball1992Pinnacle",
            "sf_set_sort_s":"Baseball1992Pinnacle",
            "sport_s":"Baseball",
            "cardnumber":"308",
            "issue_s":"",
            "id":"3-159682",
            "year_s":"1992",
            "team":"Los Angeles Dodgers",
            "set_name_s":"",
            "has_image":1,
            "amazon_sku":"159682",
            "amazon_sync":1,
            "sf_id":378827,
            "sf_ending_time":2222222222,
            "sf_sort_id":199230875,
            "sf_listing_type":"buy",
            "shopify_id":"1302493397094",
            "_version_":1604345060355211264
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

COMMANDS AND RESPONSES

```
[  
   {  
      "inv_location":"",
      "ean":"",
      "site_id":"3",
      "category_id":[  
         "1",
         "55",
         "2162220",
         "2715086",
         "306",
         "2352370",
         "2413461"
      ],
      "cp_id":"159682",
      "isbn":"",
      "id":"3-159682",
      "consigner":"",
      "upc_code":"0",
      "quantity":"1",
      "created_date":"2018-06-26T10:17:55Z",
      "mpn":"",
      "description":"",
      "inv_num":"",
      "cp_listing_type":"1",
      "price":"0.69",
      "title":"1992 Pinnacle #308 Darryl Strawberry NM-MT ",
      "live_status":""
   }
]


Success: {  
   "responseHeader":{  
      "status":0,
      "QTime":1
   }
}

[  
   {  
      "checklist_id":"249746",
      "brand_s":"Pinnacle",
      "featured":"",
      "sf_set_sort":"Baseball1992Pinnacle",
      "sport_s":"Baseball",
      "cardnumber":"308",
      "issue_s":"",
      "id":"3-159682",
      "year_s":"1992",
      "team":"Los Angeles Dodgers",
      "set_name_s":""
   }
]

Success: {  
   "responseHeader":{  
      "status":0,
      "QTime":1
   }
}


[  
   {  
      "has_image":{  
         "set":"1"
      },
      "id":"3-159682"
   }
]

Success: {  
   "responseHeader":{  
      "status":0,
      "QTime":1
   }
}




[  
   {  
      "amazon_sku":{  
         "set":"159682"
      },
      "amazon_sync":{  
         "set":"1"
      },
      "id":"3-159682"
   }
]

Success: {  
   "responseHeader":{  
      "status":0,
      "QTime":1
   }
}



[  
   {  
      "sf_id":{  
         "set":"378827"
      },
      "sf_ending_time":{  
         "set":"2222222222"
      },
      "sf_sort_id":{  
         "set":"199230875"
      },
      "id":"3-159682",
      "sf_listing_type":{  
         "set":"buy"
      }
   }
]


Success: {  
   "responseHeader":{  
      "status":0,
      "QTime":1
   }
}


[  
   {  
      "id":"3-159682",
      "shopify_id":{  
         "set":"1302493397094"
      }
   }
]

Success: {  
   "responseHeader":{  
      "status":0,
      "QTime":1
   }
}
```

Comment: How can we reproduce the problem?

Comment: These were created from within our system. I am sharing from the logs. I am new to Solr. I cannot understand why the first command is not stored but gets a success result. Does it have to do with CommitWithin?

Answer (score 0):

The two documents you submit have the same id. The second document overwrites the first one, since the id has to uniquely identify a document. If the id doesn't do that, change which field is defined as a uniqueKey, or use a UUID generator to get a new id each time the document is submitted. The latter will cause issues if you're trying to do updates without having the new uuid readily available, tho.

Another solution would be to prefix the id with the document type, or (depending on your use case) merge it into a single document before indexing.

Comment: You are correct, that is what was happening. I needed to use the same ID as I was just adding more information for the same record. The solution was to use "set" as I outlined below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was that the 1st and 2nd commands were full updates, and the rest were partial updates (using "set"

I change the second command to a format like this

[{"checklist_id":{"set":"249725"},"brand_s":{"set":"Pinnacle"},"featured":{"set":""},"sf_set_sort":{"set":"Baseball1992Pinnacle"},"sport_s":{"set":"Baseball"},"cardnumber":{"set":"287"},"issue_s":{"set":""},"id":"3-159694","year_s":{"set":"1992"},"team":{"set":"Milwaukee Brewers"},"set_name_s":{"set":""}}]

And all was right with the code, no lionger overwriting the first query.

Maybe this will help someone else!

Thanks
Mike